# Confused about ReadOnly and Editable annotations for .NET MVC models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This feels like a really stupid question, but it's frustrating me and I can't find the answer. I've done a lot of searching but I get the feeling I'm searching for the wrong thing.

I have a data model in a C# MVC 4 / .NET 4.5 app. The model is in a basic class library outside of the web project. The model's class only includes System.

I'd like to use [Editable(false)] and [ReadOnly] in this model, but neither are showing up as valid attributes in Intellisense (the compiler says the type or namespace cannot be found). [Serializable] works correctly.

I assume I need to add a reference in the project, or include another class/library, but I can't figure out what. I guess all the tutorials assume that everything will be contained in the same project, and it'll all work by default, but I can't figure out how to get this to work when it's in a different project.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.editableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.readonlyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Comment: Cool, thanks. So I added a project-level reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations (4.0.0.0) and now I have access to ReadOnly, but I'm still having problems with Editable. I don't see anything that implies it should be any different though -- any ideas why I can't use that yet?

Comment: please define "problems"

Comment: Nevermind, just needed to include ComponentModel.DataAnnotations in the file as well. Seems to be working now, thanks!